# How do only add to a total when a loop is true?

Tags: java, loops

I have used code for a slot machine and added a couple of things. I start with a *$100 bank (startBank)*. For each play, `if` the bet loses, the bet amount is *subtracted* from the bank. When the bet `wins`, the winnings should be *added to the bank* and `totalAmountWon`.  But it is not accumulating. The game will accumulate and then `totalAmountWon` will drop in value with the next win.  Do I have a loop out of place?

```
    userStringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Insert Money:");
    userAmountEntered = Double.parseDouble(userStringInput);
    totalUserAmountEntered += userAmountEntered;
    totalAmountWon = (amountWon + startBank);


    outputString =outputString +"[\t "+ word1 +"\t]\t\t\t [ "+ word2 +"]\t\t\t [ " + word3 +"]";

    //Compare values of word123
    if(( word1 != word2) && (word1 != word3) && (word2 != word3))
    {
        outputString = outputString +"\nYou have bet "+ totalUserAmountEntered +"\n\nYou have won $0";
    }
        startBank -= totalUserAmountEntered;

    if (((word1==word2) && (word1!=word3)) || ((word2==word3) && (word2!=word1))) 
    {
        outputString = outputString +"\nYou have bet "+ totalUserAmountEntered +"\n\nYour have won $"+(2*userAmountEntered);
        amountWon = (2*userAmountEntered);
    }
    else if (((word1==word2) && (word1==word3)) && ((word2==word3)&&(word2==word1))) 
    {
            outputString = outputString +"\n\nYour have won $"+(3*userAmountEntered);
            amountWon = (3*userAmountEntered);  
    }
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(outputString + "\n\nYou have total winnings of $"+totalAmountWon+"\n\nDo you want to play "+ "again?\n\nPress y for yes, any key for no :").charAt(0);
}
/* JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputString ); */

System.exit(0);  
}
}
```

Comment: I see no loop in your code

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is correct, There is no loop in your code snippet. Plus, It seems like incorrect "}" is added in word1, word2 & word3 comparison.   `if ( ( word1 != word2) && (word1 != word3) && (word2 != word3) ) { outputString = outputString +"\nYou have bet "+ totalUserAmountEntered +"\n\nYou have won $0"; } `. Can you please confirm if this last closing bracket is correct ?

Comment: for( int wordCount =1; wordCount<=3; wordCount++ ){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code is not sufficient and well organized to yield something fruitful about the solution of your question. But, according to my understanding of your question I think the problem is with this **wrongly placed "}"**

```
if(( word1 != word2) && (word1 != word3) && (word2 != word3))
    {
        outputString = outputString +"\nYou have bet "+ totalUserAmountEntered +"\n\nYou have won $0";
    }
        startBank -= totalUserAmountEntered;
```

Just replace this junk of code with this one:

```
if(( word1 != word2) && (word1 != word3) && (word2 != word3))
    {
        outputString = outputString +"\nYou have bet "+ totalUserAmountEntered +"\n\nYou have won $0";
        startBank -= totalUserAmountEntered;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** `totalAMountWon` replace last `else-if block` with this one:

```
else if (((word1==word2) && (word1==word3)) && ((word2==word3)&&(word2==word1))) 
    {
        outputString = outputString +"\n\nYour have won $"+(3*userAmountEntered);
        amountWon = (3*userAmountEntered);  
        totalAmountWon += amountWon;
    }
```

Comment: yes it works to subtract from the total, but if the amountWon increases, that is not showing as adding to the totalAmountWon.

Comment: @RBoyer so you got the problem fixed ?

Comment: Yes that has helped.

Comment: if it helped, you can always upvote it.. thats how SO works :)

Comment: Right but until I have 15 rep points, it doesn’t work. I’m just starting out.

Comment: No problem just keep this in mind for future .. welcome to SO :)